# Add "Appendix" before "A" for Appendix A in thesis TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, thesis

I am required to insert the word Appendix before the letter A in my dissertation Table of Contents as follows:

> Appendix A (title for appendix A)

but the latex thesis cls file: [FAU Thesis Class](http://www.physics.fau.edu/~cbeetle/FAUThesis/) I use generates only the letter A followed by the appendix title:

> A (title for appendix A)

The thesis cls file defines a "backmatter" command and the appendix is treated as a chapter.

```
\newcommand\backmatter{\appendix
\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{%
\ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}{%
\ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}}%
\def\sectionmark##1{\relax}}
```

Is there a simple fix to the above code that will add the word Appendix before the letter A in the TOC for Appendix A? Some related questions have been posted but the answers did not appear to work in this case.

Comment: Can you add a link to the thesis class itself?

Comment: I've found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690679/add-appendix-before-a-in-thesis-toc which pretty much answers the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\backmatter{
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{%
        \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}{%
        \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@chapapp\ \thechapter:  \fi  ##1}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{\relax}}
\makeatother
```

The `appendix` package adds some extra functionality for dealing with appendices. This extra functionality (including the one you need) is accessed by using the `\appendices` *environment* instead of the `\appendix` command.  So changing your thesis class `\backmatter` command to remove the `\appendix` command, along the with `[titletoc]` option of the package (which appends the appendix name to the letter in the TOC) should solve your problem.

Now in your actual thesis tex file you should do the following:

```
\backmatter
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{An appendix}
...
\end{appendices}
\bibliography{}
```

Comment: The suggestion worked except that now the word "Appendix" also  appears in front of Bibliography as well.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I've edited my answer from the very first one I posted.   Try the code again with the current version of the answer. I.e. make sure that the redefined `\backmatter` command does *not* contain any kind of `\appendix` command. (And remove your aux files.)

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Carey For others, you should still add a link to the actual class file.

Comment: I had a similar goal but didn't have \backmatter (\appendix instead)defined in my .cls so I tried to changed \backmatter to \appendix.  It gave "Appendix" before the chapter names but I lost the lettering and it returned to numbering like the regular chapters.  Instead I was able to `\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}` and then insert \appendices  before the appendix chapter headings.  I assume this is a more general solution? or maybe I just got lucky.

Comment: @Dominik you should use the `appendices` *environment* not the command `\appendices`. And yes, this is a more general solution. The specific thesis class used by Carey included the `\appendix` command in the definition of `\backmatter`, which was why it needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest solution is the most successful one.

Remove your `\newcommand`. Instead, `\documentclass[appendixprefix=Appendix]{yourDocumentClass}` should do the job just fine. (Of course, replace `yourDocumentClass` with whatever document class you are using.)

Note that you'll need to use a KOMA-script document class. You should, however, be able to make said KOMA-script class fit your requirements, unless you have some very exotic ones.

Comment: Where is `\appendixprefix` comming from?

Comment: Oops, I misread the docs. That's not a command, that's an option for `\documentclass`. Will fix right now.

Comment: This will only work for KOMA-script clsses. The OP mentions  a different class.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for pointing that out. I don't quite understand what reasons there could be against switching to a KOMA-script class, though, as they cover pretty much everything one could need.

Comment: Not everyone is fond of KOMA... your suggestion does not work for other classes