# Name of the appendices in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, appendices

I'm using `book` in LyX.
I changed the name on the text itself using this `\renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}` , but on the ToC i get:

> A Expressoes fatores de forma
>
> B Expressoes radiosidade
>
> . .

I wanted it to be like this:

> Anexo A Expressoes fatores de forma
>
> Anexo B Expressoes radiosidade
>
> . .

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15974/add-appendix-before-a-for-appendix-a-in-thesis-toc help?