# Changing "Chapter A" to "Appendix A" in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I am trying to display the appendix in my thesis TOC as

> Appendix A

instead of

> Chapter A

using our university's class file 'kfupm_thesis.cls'. Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\appendix
\chapter{Parameters}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\end{document}
```

I believe that the segment of code inside the 'kfupm_thesis.cls' file responsible for printing the appendix through the `\appendix` command is as follows (lines 581-585 and line 784):

```
\newcommand\appendix{\par   % line 581
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}% 
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}

\newcommand\appendixname{APPENDIX} % line 784
```

Going over this code, I think that the `\appendix` command should print the chapter header as `APPENDIX` instead of `CHAPTER` in TOC. However, it is not doing so. I checked the post at [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15974/add-appendix-before-a-for-appendix-a-in-thesis-toc) but did not help me. I also tried using the `appendix` package but then with using the `\begin{appendices}` and `\end{appendices}` instead of `\appendix` and using the `\chapter` command, the output is like

> APPENDIX CHAPTER A

The class file can be obtained from this dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2r036e04gbfeace/kfupm_thesis.cls?dl=0), needed to run MWE. Is there any way I can have the `\appendix` command to print `APPENDIX` in the TOC. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

P.S. I apologize for the lengthy class file, but I think that going over the mentioned lines of code may help identify the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to do with the `etoolbox`and `apptools` packages:

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\usepackage{apptools, etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {CHAPTER }}{\ifappendix{APPENDIX }\else{CHAPTER }\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\appendix
\chapter{Parameters}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you take a look at this question. It is related but addresses a different issue. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288762/hiding-sub-entries-in-the-toc-but-not-the-heading

Comment: @Bernard Very regrettably, it does not work for me: the Appendices are called Chapters in the TOC. The pdf and the source of the magnum opus can be both found at (http://freemathtexts.org/InProgress/RAFv7.1/)

Comment: @schremmer: I'll try to understand why it doesn't this week-end.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks very much but please do it at your best convenience as there is zero urgency.