# Changing “Chapter A” to “Appendix A” in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I am trying to display the appendix in my thesis TOC as

> Appendix A

instead of

> Chapter A

using our university's class file '[kfupm_thesis.cls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2r036e04gbfeace/kfupm_thesis.cls?dl=0)'.

The same question was asked and answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261361/changing-chapter-a-to-appendix-a-in-toc). But in my case I want to add appendices chapter wise so if I use command "\appendix", the numbering of subsequent chapters changes to alphabetical. That's why I think I have to use "\begin{appendices} and \end{appendices}". Now, using these commands, the already provided solution in the above mentioned post doesn't work for my case.

Here is the sample code

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Parameters}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}
\end{appendices}

\chapter{Third Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\end{document}
```

Kindly suggest a solution for this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution consists in patching the `appendices` environment:

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{apptools, etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {CHAPTER }}{\ifappendix{APPENDIX }\else{CHAPTER }\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\appendixtrue}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\begin{appendices}%
  \chapter{Parameters}
  \section{BLA}
  \subsection{BLA-BLA}
\end{appendices}

\chapter{Third Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\end{document}
```

[image]