# Hiding sub-entries in the TOC but not the heading

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, thesis

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\usepackage{apptools, etoolbox}
% code to fix TOC appendix format, irrelevant for this question
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {CHAPTER }}{\ifappendix{APPENDIX }\else{CHAPTER }\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\appendix
\chapter{Parameters}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\end{document}
```

Producing the following TOC:

[image]

In the TOC alone, I would like to keep the heading `APPENDIX A PARAMETERS` but hide all of its sub-entries i.e. `A.1 BLA` and `A1.1.1 BLA-BLA`. Can you suggest a way to do it. The class file `kfupm_thesis.cls` can be obtained from this dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2r036e04gbfeace/kfupm_thesis.cls?dl=0), needed to run MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Not very elegant: redefining `\addcontentsline`, but it works:

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\usepackage{apptools, etoolbox}
% code to fix TOC appendix format, irrelevant for this question
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {CHAPTER }}{\ifappendix{APPENDIX }\else{CHAPTER }\fi}{}{}
\AtAppendix{%
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{section}{\relax}{%
   \ifstrequal{#2}{subsection}{\relax}{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}
   }}%
   }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\appendix
\chapter{Parameters}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Other Parameters}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If `sections` etc. should be hidden, set the `tocdepth` counter to `0`, however, this might be done in `place`, i.e. write `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` to the `.toc` file, after `\appendix`.

(The `0` stands for `\chapter`, `\section` would have `1` etc., therefore `0` will restrict to toc levels down to `\chapter` only, which is normally `\part` and `\chapter` will appear.)

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\usepackage{apptools, etoolbox}
% code to fix TOC appendix format, irrelevant for this question
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {CHAPTER }}{\ifappendix{APPENDIX }\else{CHAPTER }\fi}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\chapter{Parameters}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

A version for working `LoT` and `LoF` as well.

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\usepackage{apptools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% code to fix TOC appendix format, irrelevant for this question
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {CHAPTER }}{\ifappendix{APPENDIX }\else{CHAPTER }\fi}{}{}
\pretocmd{\listoffigures}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\listoftables}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\chapter{Parameters}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\section{BLA}
\subsection{BLA-BLA}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works, however, if there are tables and figures in the document, the `LIST OF FIGURES` and `LIST OF TABLES` vanish. They just display a blank page with headings only, no actual lists. Is there a work-around?

Comment: @AdeelSabir: Did you mention tables and figures at all? No, you didn't

Comment: That's right, in the MWE there aren't any tables of figures. However, in that actual manuscript (very long) that I am writing, there are. It'd be great if you could suggest a solution that also take those into account. Thanks a lot for the input!

Comment: @AdeelSabir: See the update please!