# appendix instead of chapter in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, include

In the table of content, I want to have Appendix A instead of chapter A, Appendix B instead of chapter B, and show on. I can't show this when I use `\include{appendix}`. Following is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{}% adds dot after chapter title in ToC
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}% adds leader dots from chapter titles to page numbers
% chapter and chapter number rather than just number
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables 
\include{chp1}
\include{chp2}
\appendix
\include{appendix} : 
\end{document}

%chp1.txt is 
\chapter{Introduction1}
%chp2.txt is 
\chapter{Introduction2}

%appendix.txt is 

% Appendix A
\chapter{}
\section{hello1}
In the ...
\section{hello2 }

 % Appendix B
\clearpage
\newpage
\chapter{}

\section{bello1}
\section{bello2 }
```

%table of content output

```
Contents
    List of Tables . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .2
    Chapter 1 Introduction1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 3
    Chapter 2 Introduction2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 4
    Chapter A . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  .5
    A.1 hello1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  5
    A.2 hello2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .5
    Chapter B . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
    B.1 bello1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  6
    B.2 bello2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  6
```

P.S. I am NOT looking for the solution with `\input{appendix}` for `\include{appendix}`. I already tried that; although it works for this example, it does not solve my real problem.

Desired table of content output:

```
Contents
List of Tables . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .2
Chapter 1 Introduction1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 3
Chapter 2 Introduction2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 4
Appendix A . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .5
A.1 hello1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  5
A.2 hello2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .5
Appendix B . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .6
B.1 bello1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  6
B.2 bello2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  6
```

Comment: Please see my  answer to a [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261361/changing-chapter-a-to-appendix-a-in-toc/261372#261372).

Comment: Thanks. But with report class, I didn't get that output.

Comment: I'd say it's because you load `tocloft` which must have some interaction with my code. Anyway, your code gives you what you want, or do I miss something?

Comment: As to my code, it doesn't. If you see my expected output and actual output, you see that there is chapter A instead of Appendix A and chapter B instead of Appendix B. With regard to your solution, I ran your code without loading `tocloft`.

Comment: On my system, compiling your code  produces ‘appendix A’, &c.. However I didn't input files, I directly used their contents in the main file.

Comment: You are correct. The problem doesn't occur when I don't use `include{appendix}` (directly use contents in the main file). However, I do have to use `include{appendix}` and hence the question. Thanks once again.

Comment: I'll try to think about the problem tomorrow.

Comment: i don't get the problem AND I used \include{appendix}.  I did replace the \include{chp1} and \include{chp2} though.

Comment: @John: That is also true. But, still I do need to use `include{chp1}` and `\include{chp2}`.

Comment: I certainly didn't expect it, but adding the other includes caused the problem.  Anyway, putting \appendix into the appendix.tex file fixes it.  You may have to add it to every appendix file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the `\appendix` command from the main file to `appendix.tex` is one of many ways to fix the problem.  (Reproducing the problem is the hard part)  Having multiple `\appendix` commands doesn't harm anything except resetting the `chapter` counter each time.

Everything else is the same except for `appendix.tex`:

```
\appendix
% Appendix A
\chapter{}
\section{hello1}
In the ...
\section{hello2 }

 % Appendix B
\clearpage
\newpage
\chapter{}

\section{bello1}
\section{bello2 }
```